# PDF.js not opening PDF file if it is not in the same folder of viewer.html

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I want to open PDF files using PDF.js which are stored in different folder.

This is example of my folder structure

```
/files/
/files/home.html
/files/contact.html
/files/TestPDF.html
/pdfviewer/web/viewer.html
/pdf/upload/1.pdf
/pdf/upload/2.pdf
/pdf/upload/3.pdf
```

I am struggling to make it work when PDF file is in different folder.

If i keep pdf files in `/pdfviewer/web/` folder then it works fine.

I have tried few combination of paths but it is still not working.

Example TestPDF.html

```
<a href="../pdfviewer/web/viewer.html?file=http://localhost:54923/pdf/uploads/1.pdf"> OPEN </a>

<a href="../pdfviewer/web/viewer.html?file=./pdf/uploads/2.pdf"> OPEN </a>

<a href="../pdfviewer/web/viewer.html?file=/pdf/uploads/3.pdf"> OPEN </a>
```

I have to implement this in asp.net web form application

Comment: Have you tried something like this: <a href="../pdfviewer/web/viewer.html?file=../pdf/uploads/3.pdf"> OPEN </a> ?

Comment: Yes, i tried multiple combination of `../` , `../../`, `../../../` it still doesn't work

Comment: only absolute path works `http://localhost:54923/pdf/uploads/1.pdf`